# How to stop ng-model from overriding server side values

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have a asp.net webforms textbox in which I have loaded data form datatable on page load, it works fine but when I put ng-model in this, the textbox becomes blanks.
I need data from datatable as well as do some calculation in angular js .

Here is my server side code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
try
{
DataTable dt2 = bllproduct.GetProductById(productId);
if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
{
txtCp.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dt2.Rows[0]["CostPrice"]).ToString();

}
```

My angular code:

```
app.controller('ProductController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.vat=13;
    $scope.ACP = function () {
        $scope.acp = ($scope.cp - (-$scope.cp * ($scope.vat / 100)));
    }
    $scope.SP = function () {
        $scope.sp = ($scope.acp - (-$scope.acp * ($scope.margin / 100)));
    }
});
```

My TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCp" CssClass="form-control" ng-model="cp"
             ng-change="ACP()" runat="server">
```

Comment: You can't use angular bindings with `runat="server"`.  Angular is *client side JavaScript*.

Comment: I think the value of cp is empty or null. can u just try to print the value of cp in UI as expression like this {{ cp}}and make sure that you are getting the value